# Nullpointer when using JPanel

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, null-pointer

```
for(creature a : horde.creatures){
```

always throws a nullpointer, even though I defined it before:

```
private swarm horde;
```

This is the swarm class:

```
public class swarm {
public creature creatures[] = new creature[100];
}
```

which is just an array of creatures:

```
public class creature {
Random r = new Random();
public boolean hostile = r.nextBoolean();
public double[] velocity = new double[2];
public double[] position = new double[2];
```

The whole window class:

```
package de.towdo.intellia;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

final public class window {

JFrame frame;
DrawPanel drawPanel;

private swarm horde;

public static void main(String[] args){
    new window().go();
}

private void go(){
    frame = new JFrame("Window");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocation(340, 55);
    moveIt();

}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        for(creature a : horde.creatures){
            if(a.hostile){
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
            else{
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            g.fillRect((int)a.position[0], (int)a.position[1], 1, 1);
        }
    }
}

private void moveIt(){
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `horde` is not instantiated

Comment: You declared a variable but didn't initialize it. Try this: `private swarm horde = new swarm();`

Comment: This still ends in a nullpointer, just this time in line 37: if(a.hostile){.     Is there maybe the same problem in the swarm class?

Comment: You never initialize any `creature` objects either. You have an array for them, but never create actual `creature`s.

Comment: You have declared an array but, the items inside array should be also declared. creature[i]=new creature() like that.